# A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um recebimento

Tags: entity-framework, webforms, wcf

Tenho um web site que comunicado com um WCF. Esse Wcf comunica com o meu "DAO" que é uma class Library onde tenho o modelo.edmx para acesso ao banco. 
Referênciei meu DAO no WCF, e meu WCF no meu web site.

Estou usando entity framework e webForms.

Na Inner Exception está gerando o seguinte erro.

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um
>   recebimento.

No meu código gera o seguinte erro.

> Erro ao receber a resposta HTTP para
>    `http://locahost:4614/Service.svc.` Isso pode estar relacionado ao fato
>   de que a associação de ponto de extremidade do serviço não utiliza o
>   protocolo HTTP. Também pode estar relacionado à anulação de um
>   contexto de solicitação HTTP pelo servidor (possivelmente devido ao
>   desligamento do serviço). Consulte os logs do servidor para obter mais
>   detalhes

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione na sua `connectionString` no arquivo `Web.config`:

```
"MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

Exemplo:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MeuSistema;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

Comment: @Marconi Esse "transformar" a gente chama "serializar". Pra responder sua pergunta vou precisar de exemplos de código. Pode por favor editar a pergunta?

Answer (score -2):

Outra solução para a mesma mensagem de erro:

> O entity por padrão está configurado para gerar um proxy
>   automaticamente, a solução então é desativar essa opção com o comando
>   abaixo:
>
> DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
>
> Alberto Amorim
>   https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/wcf-entityframework-5-code-first/426154

Comment: Camila, seja bem vinda ao SO-pt. Geralmente aqui no site adicionamos link com seu conteúdo. Links por si só quebram e deixam o conteúdo inutilizável. Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site!

Comment: vlw Marconi e Everson, desatenção minha, já providenciei a alteração do post.